# instafeedjs doesn't work on my site

Tags: instafeedjs

I'm trying to set up instafeedjs but it doesn't work.

```
script type="text/javascript" src="/instafeed.min.js"></script>
     <script>
  var feed = new Instafeed({
  clientId: '377e47596dcf4fc284d36fe0098700ba',
  useHttp: true
  });
  feed.run();
</script>
```

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? Are you seeing errors in your console? If so, what are they?

Comment: No it just doesn't appear.

Comment: Have you added `<div id="instafeed"></div>` to your page? Also make sure the code you pasted above is at the bottom of your page, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: In 2020 you can just use: https://www.instafeed.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sue the, you have done the following steps in your code.

1. Added a div tag with id "instafeed"
2. Mapped the instafeed.js library correctly.

Refer the code blog below for more info.

```js
  var feed = new Instafeed({
  clientId: '377e47596dcf4fc284d36fe0098700ba',
  useHttp: true
  });
  feed.run();
```

```html
<script src="http://sriajith.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/instafeed.min_.js"></script>
<div id="instafeed"/>
```